# MySQL Remove/Combine Similar Rows and it's references

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have 2 tables: Tags and Post_Tags_relationship

**Tag table** has 3 columns - ID(primary), Title and URL
**Post_Tags_relationship table** has 2 columns - Tag_ID AND  Post_ID (primary is the combination of both)

There are a lot of similar tags title and url in the Tags table, I want to delete all replicated records and also modify the Post_Tags_relationship to update the deleted tag id with the existing one, and if this update will return duplicate id error then remove it.

So if **Tag table** has:

```
ID= 20, Title = News Section, URL = news-section
ID= 68, Title = News Section, URL = news-section
```

**Post_Tags_relationship** has:

````
Post_ID = 56, Tag_ID = 20
Post_ID = 80, Tag_ID = 20
Post_ID = 500, Tag_ID = 68
Post_ID = 584, Tag_ID = 20
Post_ID = 695, Tag_ID = 20
Post_ID = 695, Tag_ID = 68```
````

If we delete ID 20 from Tags table, the Post_Tags_relationship will look like:

````
Post_ID = 56, Tag_ID = 68
Post_ID = 80, Tag_ID = 68
Post_ID = 500, Tag_ID = 68
Post_ID = 584, Tag_ID = 68
Post_ID = 695, Tag_ID = 68 // deplicate Primary key I want this to be removed please.
Post_ID = 695, Tag_ID = 68 // ```
````

I hope this makes sense, please let me know if you will have any questions.

Comment: How do you determine which Tag_ID to keep?

Comment: It doesn't matter, any tag can be deleted as long as the related posts for this tag is converted to the existing tag.

Comment: @AhmedEssam    thanks

Comment: How is a tag duplicate defined? Do `title` and `url` both have to be equal? Or only `title`? Or only `url`?

Comment: Title is unique  and also url is unique.so title could be News Section and Url could be news-section Or title van be news and url news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find tag duplicates and store them in a "temporary" table:

```sql
drop table if exists tmp_tags_duplicates;
create table tmp_tags_duplicates
    select t1.id, min(t0.id) as duplicate_of
    from tags t1
    join tags t0 using(title, url)
    where t1.id > t0.id
    group by t1.id;
```

Find already inserted duplicates in `posts_tags` table (which need to be deleted). Store them in another "temporary" table:

```sql
drop table if exists tmp_to_delete;
create table tmp_to_delete
    select pt1.*, d.duplicate_of
    from posts_tags pt1
    join tmp_tags_duplicates d on d.id = pt1.tag_id
    join posts_tags pt0 
      on  pt0.post_id = pt1.post_id
      and pt0.tag_id  = d.duplicate_of;
```

Find entries in `posts_tags` which need to be updated. Store them in a third "temporary" table:

```sql
drop table if exists tmp_to_update;
create table tmp_to_update
    select pt1.*, d.duplicate_of
    from posts_tags pt1
    join tmp_tags_duplicates d on d.id = pt1.tag_id
    left join posts_tags pt0 
      on  pt0.post_id = pt1.post_id
      and pt0.tag_id  = d.duplicate_of
    where pt0.tag_id is null;
```

Delete duplicates in `posts_tags`:

```sql
delete pt
from posts_tags pt
join tmp_to_delete t using(post_id, tag_id);
```

Update `tag_id` in `posts_tags`:

```sql
update posts_tags pt
join tmp_to_update t using(post_id, tag_id)
set pt.tag_id = t.duplicate_of;
```

Delete duplicates in `tags`table

```sql
delete t
from tags t
join tmp_tags_duplicates using(id);
```

Delete the "temporary" tables.

```sql
drop table tmp_tags_duplicates;
drop table tmp_to_delete;
drop table tmp_to_update;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/FUWZG89399

Now define proper UNIQUE and FOREIGN keys, so you won't need to fix it ever again.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul,  this answer seems to fix the issue, i will test it first thing in the morning when i jave access to my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an outline how I would approach this problem, I will assume your table isn't large and the queries aren't expensive:

1. Select all distinct titles from Tag Table, this can be done using the `DISTINCT` keyword. This will give the titles without replication:

   SELECT DISTINCT Title FROM Tag
2. Loop the resulting titles and make a new query to the tags table for each title to get all duplicated fields for this specific title. You will end up getting rows with the same title.
3. Loop the rows with the same title replacing each one of them with the ID you want to keep and in the same time replacing this ID in the Post_Tags_relationship. All done with `UPDATE` statement

To avoid problems like this in the future use foreign keys. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

**Update:**

To avoid the error that will occur because of the duplicate primary key you can create an array and in the loop add to it every post id and if the post id already exists, delete this record from the table. Something like this:

```
$post_ids = array()
//...
// Duplicate fields loop
if ( in_array( $pid, $post_ids ) ) { 
// The post has the tag already
// Delete this record from table
// ..

} else {
   $post_ids[] = $pid
   // Update fields
   // ..
}
```

Comment: But uodate the relationship table will return duplicate primary key error in some cases.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look tomorrow.